# Owin CultureInfo & AspNetSynchronizationContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, async-await, owin

net application which both makes usage of Mvc (5.2.3) & WebApi (2.2). Now My application is built and initialized by owin Startup class (Global.asax has been deleted) with the package **Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb** installed.

Previously, in the ages of Global.asax, I was setting up the *current request culture* by taking culture by cookie or AcceptLanguage header and setting up **Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(langSelectedValue)** even for CurrentUiCulture.

Now, as my Global.asax has passed away leaving the setup in Startup.cs, the code to *mimic* the previous culture setup is in a

```
app.Use(async (env, next) => {
var langCookie = env.Request.Cookies["cultureName"];
if (langCookie != null && GlobalizationHelper.IsValidCultureCode(langCookie))
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(langCookie);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(langCookie);
}
await next();
})
```

The problem is clear, all async requests get lost the Thread culture. I tried many solutions:

1. the owin globalization module, but it's not for me, I don't want to change my routing, which is based on attributes...
2. the synchronizationcontext for preserve and apply the culture, but the webapi/mvc stack even if I set my own SynchronizationContext continue using the AspNetSynchronizationContext
3. the WithCulture() extension methods with a customized Awaiter for culture, but nothing done

I appreciate any suggestion to apply the CultureInfo and preserve it in a Owin async application.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe you'll need to upgrade to .NET 4.6 for this.

Comment: I've done, my solution now it's completely on .NET 4.6 but the problem is still here

Comment: Is your [`targetFramework` set to 4.6 in your web.config](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework.aspx)?

Comment: sure! it's the first thing I checked...

Comment: have you been able to solve it ? In my case it worked in 4.5.1 but since upgrading to 4.6 it doesn't work any more.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35910161/asp-net-middleware-doesnt-preserve-culture-anymore