# Asp.Net WebForms 4.62 async operation lost current culture

Tags: asp.net, .net, asynchronous, webforms

I have an async WebForms Page (.Net Framework 4.62) and I set the culture in the `InitializeCulture` method, see below code.

I run some async operation by using the page `RegisterAsyncTask` method.

The callback for the async operation (on another thread) loses the `CurrentCulture`. The `DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` have the right culture, but `CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` is wrong. Did anyone solve the same trouble?

```cs
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{    
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = currentCulture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
    CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = currentCulture;
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = currentCulture;
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = currentCulture;
}
```

This trouble with lost culture began when I updated .Net Framework from 4.51 to 4.62. With WebForms page setting `async` set to true, I have the default thread culture in the `PreRenderComplete` event instead of the current culture set in the `InitializeCulture` method.

It does not depend on whether I register some async operation or not. I know that async operation callback can be on another thread, but I see a bad culture before an async operation is executed, at the start of the async method.

The trouble after the async method execution can be solved with some custom synchronization context, atd...

Comment: Are you sure you're actually on the same thread you set it ?

Answer (score 2):

We had the same issue. We fixed it by adding the following setting:

```
<add key="appContext.SetSwitch:Switch.System.Globalization.NoAsyncCurrentCulture" value="true" />
```

See [OwinMiddleware doesn't preserve culture change in .net 4.6.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36455801/owinmiddleware-doesnt-preserve-culture-change-in-net-4-6/37520214#37520214) and [ASP.NET Middleware doesn't preserve culture anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35910161/asp-net-middleware-doesnt-preserve-culture-anymore).

Comment: May I ask if you do understand why it fixes the issue? My understanding of the NoAsyncCurrentCulture switch is that it deactivates the flow of culture settings between threads, which is what we try to avoid. I'm kind of lost.

Comment: I think that when async=true is activated on a page, a child thread is changing its Culture/UICulture to the default values instead of relying on the "flow of culture". That change is then propagated back to the main thread thanks to the "flow of culture". From my perspective, using the NoAsyncCurrentCulture switch is a hack to fix something else I would like to understand...

Comment: @BenjaminTalmard The handling of thread culture has been changed in .net 4.6, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/#whats-new-in-net-2015 "Changes to the task-based asynchronous pattern (TAP)" and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo#Async. 

According to https://github.com/riganti/dotvvm/issues/330, my best guess is that the setting of the culture doesn't flow back to the 'parent' thread, causing this issue.

Comment: I have not checked, but it looks to me this workaround may well cause issues with culture for MVC or API if your web project mixes them with WebForm, as do ours, which is undergoing a progressive migration to these.  
Instead, we set the culture to its appropriate value in the `Page_PreRenderComplete` event too, for at least having the "view" (aspx) rendered in the adequate language.